# PHP Functions repository

Tags: php, function

I am wondering if you know any source where we can find premade functions in PHP ?
A sort of open-source repository where functions are tested and created taking in mind security and best practices. For example : generating mails, field escape functions, login, register, ... the classic stuff.

Comment: Any decent framework does what you described (and more), just pick one?

Comment: Right however I'm more a notepad coder. But there again it's really local to a framework. Looking for a website where a development community propose and reworks functions. To come up with some great functions.

Comment: Not exactly functions per se, but this is a really great list of library and frameworks (or generally a collection of useful links): [Link](https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php)

Comment: That's great :) Bookmarked it, however as useful as it is, it is still a bunch of articles scattered explaining good practices but not providing fast & safe functions reworked by the community. If it does not exist, I might create it :3

Comment: here is one that is generally useful that is based off underscore.js http://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are MANY such packages available at https://packagist.org/.  You autoload these into your PHP app using Composer, available at https://getcomposer.org/.  This is the newest, bestest way to developer PHP apps.  Don't re-invent the wheel; use some of the great code available here.